# Need to enter the value of username in a webpage opened through a function in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

On button click in wpf view, the webpage should open in the background and there is a field for username in webpage that should be auto-filled.
The method to open webpage I am using is :
Process.Start("https://example.com/");

Using this it opens the webpage in the foreground of the wpf application.
Used this.Topmost= true; for the MainWindow of wpf applications, this just keeps the main wpf application in the top.

I want 2 things,
1.) the other webpage that I am opening through the wpf application, that should be opened in a minimized mode.
2.) I want to enter the username automatically in the webpage opened through wpf application's button click.

Comment: Do you have control over the web page you're opening? I. e. can you make it handle a query string in the way you want to?

Comment: Thank You for the reply.No, I do not have control over the web page as it is a third party web page . I am not sure how to check and query for the control that they have for entering the username, Please advise me with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimized window style for the process with the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle?view=netframework-4.8) by following the example on the documentation page. Also for the web page to display the user name you need to provide that as a query string parameter and then handle that in the page itself.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I had tried using this for opening the webpage in the minimized mode but it still opens in the top , not in minimized mode.
Code i tried is:
ProcessStartInfo theProcess = new ProcessStartInfo("https://example.com/");
theProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(theProcess);

Please guide me if I missed something?